# Cisco Anyconnect flashes then disappears

Tags: 12.04, vpn, cisco

I have installed the Cisco Anyconnect secure mobility client on my ubuntu 12.05 laptop using the vpnsetup.sh. It always works immediately after running the script but once I power-down then come back later it will just flash on the screen then go away. If I re-run the vpnsetup.sh it will work fine. This never happened until a couple of weeks ago I chose to accept all updates and did a mass update on my laptop. This has been occurring ever since.

I'm pretty new to linux and need some help troubleshooting. I really want to learn the system better and could use some guidance in troubleshooting issues like this in the future so I don't have to keep bothering the experts.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after much searching and digging-around, I managed to fix this issue by adding the following line to rc.local:

/etc/init.d/vpnagentd_init start

Not sure this is the best solution. But, alas, it is the only one I could find that worked. If anybody more saavy at linux than I could chime-in to let me know if this is a suitable solution or not, it would be very much appreciated. Otherwise, I am marking this as the answer.

Best.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/vpnagentd start` worked for me on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Cisco annyconnect. Initially I got the same issue, the vpnagent blinks and then closes. The entry in /var/log did not show sign of a crash. The anser by RockyMountainHigh did not help in my case. At: 
https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/vpn/vpnagentd-crash-on-linux/td-p/2524709

there is a description where the vpnagent crashed with a solution to run:

/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnagent
followed by
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnul

Here I received an error message that vpnnul could not find 
libpangox-1.0.so.0!
After I installed libpangox-1.0.so.0 the vpnagent finally worked. 
I am not sure what other dependencies might exist. I had installed a 'normal' installation, followed by several software related libraries like:
libX11-dev, libXmu-dev, libreadline-de, libpng-dev 
My guess is these are not relevant.
Best